# Plot the evolution of an LDA topic across time

Tags: r, ggplot2, tm, lda, topic-modeling

I'd like to plot how the proportion of a particular topic changes over time, but I've been having some trouble isolating a single topic and plotting over time, especially for plotting multiple groups of documents separately (let's create two groups to compare - journals A and B). I've saved dates associated with these journals in a function called `dateConverter`.

Here's what I have so far (with much thanks to @scoa):

```
library(tm); library(topicmodels);


txtfolder <- "~/path/to/documents/"
source <- DirSource(txtfolder)

myCorpus <- Corpus(source, readerControl=list(reader=readPlain))


for (i in 1:10){
  meta(myCorpus[[i]], tag = "origin") <- "A"
}
for (i in 11:length(myCorpus)){
  meta(myCorpus[[i]], tag = "origin") <- "B"
}
dates <- do.call("c", dateConverter)
for (i in 1:length(myCorpus)){
  meta(myCorpus[[i]], tag = "datetimestamp") <- dates[i]
}

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(myCorpus, control = list(minWordLength=3))


n.topics <- 10
lda.model <- LDA(dtm, n.topics)
terms(lda.model,10)
df <- data.frame(id=names(topics(lda.model)),
                 topic=posterior(lda.model),
                 date=as.POSIXct(unlist(lapply(meta(myCorpus,type="local",tag="datetimestamp"),as.character))),
                 origin=unlist(meta(myCorpus,type="local",tag="origin"))    )
```

How can I plot these?

Comment: your code is not reproducible. You do not provide the dataset (you could use a tm built-in dataset like `data(acq)` if you don't want to share yours), `dateConverter` is not defined, and I am quite sure the data.frame is giving an error because `posterior(lda.model)` will give a list of two data.frames and you are assigning it to a single data.frame column. Please provide those informations, try to adapt the code I gave for the plot in the other question's answer, and tell us precisely what is wrong with it (what is the ouput and how is it not expected ? what error does it throw?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just an adaptation of my previous answer :

```
## Load the data
library(tm)

## Use built-in data set
data(acq)
myCorpus <- acq

## prepare the data
for (i in 1:25){
  meta(myCorpus[[i]], tag = "origin") <- "A"
}

for (i in 26:length(myCorpus)){
  meta(myCorpus[[i]], tag = "origin") <- "B"
}

dates <- sample(seq.Date(as.Date("2013-01-01"),as.Date("2014-01-01"),length.out=8),50, replace=TRUE)

for (i in 1:length(myCorpus)){
  meta(myCorpus[[i]], tag = "datetimestamp") <- dates[i]
}

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(myCorpus, control = list(minWordLength=3))


library(topicmodels)    
n.topics <- 5
lda.model <- LDA(dtm, n.topics)
terms(lda.model,10)
```

Reshape data for plotting. I take the mean posterior for each group of topics, date and origin.

```
df <- data.frame(id=names(topics(lda.model)),                 
                 date=as.POSIXct(unlist(lapply(meta(myCorpus,type="local",tag="datetimestamp"),as.character))),
                 origin=unlist(meta(myCorpus,type="local",tag="origin"))    )

dft <- cbind(df,posterior(lda.model)$topics)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
M <- gather(dft,topic,value,-id,-date,-origin) %>%
  group_by(topic,date,origin) %>%
  summarize(value=mean(value))
```

Plot

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(M,aes(x=date,color=origin,y=value)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(topic~origin)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so, so much for this. I promise that I've been working at fixing everything that you mentioned - making it reproducible, and utilizing your previous answer - but R has been chugging away at some calculations nonstop for the last day or so, so I was mostly waiting until tomorrow... But again, thank you!